# Intermittent JUnit error - java virtual machine connection refused

Tags: java, junit, jvm, jmockit

I'm getting intermittent JUnit 4 errors in our Jenkins build system. The test passes after re-running it. The test is started by Maven and uses JMockit for mock objects.

The root cause of the exception comes from the VM:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Connection refused
at sun.tools.attach.LinuxVirtualMachine.connect(Native Method)
at sun.tools.attach.LinuxVirtualMachine.<init>(LinuxVirtualMachine.java:124)
```

Anyone experienced this and found a solution?

Comment: I don't know what would cause that, but a workaround is to use the `-javaagent:jmockit.jar` JVM initialization parameter instead of letting JMockit use the Attach API. For details, see http://jmockit.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/www/tutorial/RunningTests.html#maven

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like its a bug in the JVM https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6649594

The workaround was to pass a JVM argument:

```
-XX:+StartAttachListener
```

and the tests stopped failing.